# Validation for tabs?

Tags: javascript

i have four tabs in my page with thier corresponding fields...
i want  if a particular tab is selected then only the fields of that tab i want to validate in javascript

```
<div class="tabcontents">
        <div id="view1">
          <table >
            <tr>
                <td width="293"><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">**</span>Plan Name:</td><td colspan="3"> 
                    <input type="text" name="planName" id="planName" value=""/></td>
                <td width="172"><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">**</span>Price:</td><td width="262" colspan="3"> 
                    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td width="172"><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">**</span>Billing Code:</td><td width="262" colspan="3"> 
                    <input type="text" name="billingCode" id="billingCode" value=""/></td></tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div id="view2">
           <table width="936">
           <tr>
                <td width="137">Group Id:</td><td colspan="3"> 
                    <input type="text" name="groupId" id="groupId" value=""/></td>
                <td width="194">Group Primary CTN:</td><td width="263" colspan="3"> 
                    <input type="text" name="groupPrimaryCTN" id="groupPrimaryCTN" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
           </table>               
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check you condition inside the validation function
make an event on submit method

```
function checkValidation()
{
    var returnValue=false;

    //make four different condition for all tabs ..like
    if( document.getElementById("view1").style.display == "none" )
    {
        returnValue = validationForTab1();

    } else if (document.getElementById("view2").style.display == "none")
    {
         returnValue = validationForTab2();

    } else if (document.getElementById("view3").style.display == "none")
    {
         returnValue = validationForTab3();

    } else if (document.getElementById("view4").style.display == "none")
    {
          returnValue = validationForTab4();
    }

    return returnValue ; 
}

validationForTab1()
{

}
 validationForTab2()
{

}
 validationForTab3()
{

}
 validationForTab4()
{

}
```

it's little bit hard process but you can code it easily ...

Comment: and now how i will check if the corresponding fields are empty or not??

Comment: you can write your validation for tab's corresponding fields in their validation methods ...for validation process you can see here ...   http://stackoverflow.com/a/17804733/2782669