# How to get the value of textbox ( which is inside Gridview) in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I want to validate that textbox  if it is empty  it should give alert message that "textbox cannot be empty"

I have searched this site but i didn't get any satisfied answer.
Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a textbox is empty in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659098/checking-if-a-textbox-is-empty-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this function

```
  function validate(){
         var textbox=documnet.getElementById('textboxid');

         if(textbox.value=="" ||textbox.value==null){
               alert("textbox cannot be empty");
         }
 }
```