# Javascript text alert

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

How can I use JavaScript to recognize  if a text box is filled, and if not, to alert me that it must be filled.

I have tried using

```
function myFunction() {
    alert
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a textbox is empty in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659098/checking-if-a-textbox-is-empty-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following fiddle, but its better if you google your query because it is just a basic query:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var inputVal = $("input[name=input]").val();
  if(inputVal == "" || inputVal == null){
    alert("Please fill the box");
  }else{
    alert("Good to go");
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/s7bovqvw/