# Loader pops up and hangs when there is a form error on page submission

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am currently using this javascript to popup a loader when I click the submit button. The loader works fine when there is no form error and shows the response after waiting. However, the loader keeps spinning when there is a form input error popup and the request does not get submitted to backend but loader keeps spinning infinitely.

```
    <div id="loader" class= "lds-dual-ring hidden overlay" >
        <div class="lds-dual-ring hidden overlay"> </div>
       <div class="loadcontent"><div><strong>Working on your request...it may take up to 2 minutes.</strong></div></div>

    </div>
```

````
    $('#submitBtn').click(function () {


        $('#loader').removeClass('hidden')
        // $('#loader').html('Loading').addClass('loadcontent')

  


        // $("#loading").html("Loading");

    })
</script>```
Here is the line where the pattern is being matched and form validation is being done upon clicking submit.
````

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-control"style="padding: 0;">
            
                {% ifequal field.name 'Port' %} 

                {% render_field field class="rowforinput marginforfields form-control" style="height: 23px; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0" title=" For eg. 1/1/48 or 2/1/16" pattern="^[12]/1/(?:[1-3]\d|4[0-8]|[1-9])$" required=true %}

            {% endifequal %}           </div>
    </div>
```

```
How can I make this loader script run only when there is no form input error? I am using Django, Javascript, html and I am a beginner in JS.
```

Comment: You're not showing us enough of your code. We need to see how the error handling works too, as it would likely be something like `$('#submitBtn').click( () => { if (!error) { $('#loader').removeClass('hidden') } });`

Comment: just added some missing code. That's all I am using for the loader to show up upon clicking submit. Probably error handling is what is missing. Can you guide me further?

Comment: Doesn't look like you've got any error handling there yet.  Within that function (after submit button pressed), but before you show the loader, add some code which checks that the required fields are completed properly - if they are, show the loader, if they're not show an error message.

Comment: I am not sure about how to add the error handling though. Can you help please?

Comment: Without a lot more context it's quite hard to help, and the question is too broad for StackOverflow. I reccomend breaking it down into small steps. E.g. for checking that a text field is empty, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14659279/979052) :)

Comment: Please tell me what information you need. I believe it's something simple but I just can't get my head around this because of very little JS experience. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, my main ask is : how can I start loader ONLY when the form validation is correct? I also updated how the form validation is being done in Django.

Comment: @Lissy93 I posted the solution. It was a very simple solution. I think I didn't communicate the problem well but the solution was in the given code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I asked so many people for the solution but I guess no one was able to understand this without looking at the complete and hence no one provided solution, finally here is the solution:

my javascript was getting triggered on the "click" event, instead I had to change it to the "submit" event for my form id. That's it!!

so my new javascript code looks like:

```
   $('#configForm').submit(function () {


        $('#loader').removeClass('hidden')
        console.log("HERE LOADER")
        // $('#loader').html('Loading').addClass('loadcontent')

  


        // $("#loading").html("Loading");

    })
</script>
```

That's all, that's the solution.